# Proving the indefinite integral $\int \frac{1}{u(a+bu)}du $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**How can I prove that the definite integral:**

$\int \frac{1}{u(a+bu)}du  $

**is equal to:**

$\frac{1}{a} ln|\frac{u}{a+bu}| +C $

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions?

Comment: Try differentiating the antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

Partial fractions is a very direct way to do this

$${A\over u}+{B\over a+bu}={1\over u(a+bu)}\iff A(a+bu)+Bu=1$$

Then setting $u=0$ we get $A={1\over a}$. Setting $u=-{a\over b}$ we get $B=-{b\over a}$.

So you're just integrating:

> $${1\over a}\left(\int{1\over u}-{b\over a+bu}\right)\,du = {1\over a}\log\left|{u\over a+bu}\right|+C$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{u(a+bu)}=\frac{A}{u}+\frac{B}{a+bu}=\frac{A(a+bu)+Bu}{u(a+bu)}=\frac{(Ab+B)u+Aa}{u(a+bu)}$$

So:

$$Aa=1 \Rightarrow A=\frac{1}{a}$$

$$Ab+B=0 \Rightarrow B=-\frac{b}{a}$$

Therefore:

$$\int \frac{1}{u(a+bu)}du=\frac{1}{a} \int \frac{1}{u} du-\frac{b}{a} \int \frac{1}{a+bu}du=\frac{1}{a} \ln |u|-\frac{1}{a} \ln |a+bu|+c \\ =\frac{1}{a} \ln |\frac{u}{a+bu}|+c$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int \frac{1}{u(a+bu)}du =\frac1a\int \frac{a}{u(a+bu)}du =\frac1a\int \frac{a+bu-bu}{u(a+bu)}du=\frac1a\int \frac{1}{(u)}du-\frac1a\int \frac{b}{(a+bu)}du==\frac1a\int \frac{1}{(u)}du-\frac1a\int \frac{d(bu)}{(a+bu)}$
$$\\$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

One way (which is not the most informative way, but is probably the fastest) is just to differentiate

$$
\frac{1}{a} \text{log} |{\frac{u}{a + bu}|}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int\frac{1}{u(a+bu)}du$

$ = \int\frac{1}{u^2(\frac{a}{u}+b)}du$

Let $x = \frac{a}{u}+b = \frac{a+bu}{u}$,   $dx = -a\frac{1}{u^2}$

$ = -\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{1}{x}dx$

$ = \frac{1}{a}\ln{\frac{1}{x}}$

$ = \frac{1}{a}\ln|{\frac{u}{a+bu}}|$